# Forcing USB device to install outdated drivers

Tags: usb, emulator, device-driver

I've got two old dance pads lying around here which should work on windows XP, but don't in windows 10. They're not even recognised. I was wondering if any of you knew of some software that can emulate windows XP for some of the usb ports or let me run a USB device in compatibility mode?

Comment: I would attribute that to driver enforcement. Microsoft has included a feature, driver signature enforcement  designed to ensure that users of Microsoft can only load drivers that have been signed by Microsoft. You might want to check if your drivers comply with Microsoft standards otherwise consider *driver enforcement overrider* here: http://www.ngohq.com/?page=dseo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xavier suggested, the problem as indeed driver enforcement. The way I solved the problem was not with a third party overrider but instead using windows' on functionality.

By holding the shift key when pressing restart in the start menu of windows, you're able to enable advanced boot options. Going to Troubleshoot>Advanced options>Startup settings, you're able to disable driver signature enforcement.